# Regular Expression needed to exclude two parts within one code

Tags: regex

I have this code:

```
10641/90X
```

I need one Regular Expression which deletes both

```
/ and 0X
```

So the code that is left over should be

```
106419
```

Who can help me with this!?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What programming language do you use?

Comment: Please describe what you have tried and the programming language you want this to work in.

Comment: Why does this question receives upvotes????

Comment: And, btw, a regex can not delete anything, it can only match a pattern. The usage of a regex within a replace method is completely language dependent.

Answer (score 1):

Perl style replace:

```
s{/(\d+)0X}{\1}g;
```

Comment: thank you so far, the language is rubular. upper solution doesn't match the numbers i need. could you help me a second time?

Comment: Rubular is not a language, but a tool, and not a perfect one. For example, it does not support regex replace (but ruby does). If you use ruby, can you tell what problem you are having?

Answer (score 0):

Match pattern: `^(\d+)/(\d+)0X$`, replacement pattern: `$1$2`.

Depending on language of choice, you might need to include `/` at the beginning and end of the match, and replace `$` with `\` in the replacement pattern.

Comment: hank you so far, the language is rubular. upper solution doesn't match the numbers i need. could you help me a second time?

Answer (score 0):

python method:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'(/)|(0X)', '', '10641/90X')
'106419'
```

this replaces any instance of `/` or `0X` with nothing. which means it just removes them.

you can go a step further, if you want to extract only numbers from a string, and remove anything else no matter what, just use this:

```
>>> re.sub(r'[^\d]', '', '10641/90X')
'1064190'
```

of course, in this case, you wanted to remove the trailing `0X` so it is not as usefull. but for a similar problem it might be a good solution.

Comment: You don't need to put brackets around your alternatives, `r'/|0X'` is fine.

Comment: you are correct, but i prefer it for 2 reasons. 1. it remove ambiguity about whether the X is part of the 'or' or not. and 2, i prefer explicit coding as it is better for maintenance.

Comment: thank you so far, the language is rubular. upper solution doesn't match the numbers i need. could you help me a second time?

Comment: what is "the upper solution?", rubular is not a language. what programming language do you need. and, if it doesnt help you, maybe you can help us. give us more than 1 example of a string that needs to be extracted, give a few examples, and how each of them should look after being parsed by the regex.